# How do I go about transposing a large dataset in excel (two actions)?

Tags: excel, transpose

I'm recoding data as part of a larger, confounded factorial research project. After the first parse, I have values distributed across eight worksheets i.e., blocks (32 responses in each (32*8=256 respondents). These coded responses then need to be returned back into a master sheet for analysis. I started using TRANSPOSE but became unsure of how to replicate it across the two actions I need, especially given only one action is a shift from column to row. Additionally, it still requires a fair amount of hand-coding formulas since I could only figure out how to apply it to one block of responses at a time.

My question is: is there a combination of formulas that can be used to carry out these processes? If so, is there a better way to then replicate it easily across all respondents (i.e., the other eight sheets)?

[image: Actions screenshot]
[image: Variables screenshot]
[image: Master screenshot]

Comment: Questions: 1) You say "form needed for B2:B12". What kind of form? 2) Do you want to process all rows in Block 1 Variables-Master: sequentially, as a range of rows, or pick and chose rows? 3) Will the blocks in Results-Master always be 10x16 matrices, e.g. (An ... In x Rn ... AGn) ==> (In ... Rn x Rn ... Rm)? 4) Where do columns B-H in  Results-Master come from? Do you manually input that?

Comment: 1) that is a placeholder, I meant formula needed to copy and paste. 2) pick and choose rows. 3) yes, it will always be 10x16 but only one row (I -Q are demographic info) and column R (these are the survey responses) will have data. 4) These columns are the experiment design. It's a blocking concept used in confounded factorial designs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way using formulas. It can be done programmatically with VBA scripting. The included Excel 2016 code is from a project I did to accomplish something similar. Its a couple of dozen lines long, but easy to understand, if you have some basic Excel VBA skills. They're modified macros, run one at a time. You can change the sheet, row, and column references to adapt it to your project:

```
Sub CopyRows()
'Declare and initialize index varialbe for target row
Dim toRow As Integer
toRow = 1

'Loop through source rows
For fromRow = 5 To 22 Step 1
    
    Sheets("Readings").Select
    'Select and copy source cells
    Range(Cells(fromRow, 1), Cells(fromRow, 3)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Transpose").Select
    'Add row space to accomodate column for transposed rows
    toRow = toRow + 4
    'Select and paste to target cells
    Range(Cells(toRow, 1), Cells(toRow, 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next fromRow
End
End Sub

Public Sub TransposeCols()
'Declare and initialize index varialbe for target row
Dim toRow As Integer
toRow = 1

'Loop through source rows
For fromRow = 5 To 22 Step 1
    
    Sheets("Readings").Select
    'Select and copy source cells for transposition
    Range(Cells(fromRow, 4), Cells(fromRow, 6)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Transpose").Select
    'Add offset row space to accomodate column for transposed rows
    toRow = toRow + 5
    'Select cell in target column and paste transposed row
    Range(Cells(toRow, 4), Cells(toRow, 4)).Select
    'Performs transpose paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

Next fromRow
End
End Sub
```

**Demonstration image to debug and test code:**
[image: Demonstration]

Comment: My questions are going to get silly...quickly. After I bring your script into VBA, is there a way to progress through the subs so excel is actively highlighting affected cells. If I can see what is happening, I think I can make changes

Comment: Yes, in the VB editor, click in the grey left margin to add a code break-point (pause). It will be represented by a red dot. I break just before a paste operation. You can resume after each break, but clicking the green arrow on the toolbar, or pressing F5. I'm edited my answer to added a demonstration image at the end.

Comment: Spelling: "I'm editing my answer to add  a demonstration image at the end."